# Is it possible to re-create the Administrator user profile on a Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows

Is it possible to re-create the Administrator user profile on a Windows Server 2008?

I searched online but didn't come up with any information on doing so.

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Comment: create new user --> add to group --> Administrators ?

Comment: @krisFR So delete the existing user `Administrator`, create a new user `Administrator` and add it to that group?

Comment: No. What is not working with Administrator profile ?

Comment: Do you mean you somehow the actual account from the account database, or just the user profile under `c:\users\administrator`.  If you deleted the profile it should just get re-created when you login again.  If you are getting the 'User Profile Service failed' message see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947215

Comment: Q: Is it possible to re-create the Administrator user profile on a Windows Server 2008? A: Of course it is. Perhaps you could give us some detail on the actual problem that you're trying to solve.